# CSS | Как сделать такой макет, используя FlexBox или media-query?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

У меня есть изображение, растянутое на весь экран браузера. Мне надо наложить поверх изображения блок с Текстом 1, а также блок с Тексом 2. В зависимости от размера окна браузера,  Текст 1 должен оставаться в том же положении, но размер чуть меньше, а Текст 2 должен переходить на новую строку после изображения и примыкать к левой части. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<div class="container">
<img src="images/image.jpg" width="100%" alt="Image">
<div class="text1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div class="text2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я описала всё, привела пример кода. Мне надо сделать адаптивным такой макет, чтобы блоки не съезжали в зависимости от изменения размера экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Медиа здесь ни к чему. Можно легко сделать при помощи свойства `flex-wrap`.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;

    /* Когда блоки уже не будут помещаться в одну строку, они будут переноситься на новую */
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    /* Обязательно указываем ширину */
    width: 100%;

    /* Если картинка визуально фоновая, то она и должна быть фоновой */
    background: url("images/image.jpg") center no-repeat;
}

.container > div {
    /* Обязательно указываем ширину и минимальную ширину */
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 20rem;
}
```